# Azure App registration does not appear in Enterprise applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Recently I have created a few app registrations as per screenshot below,

[image]

The most interesting thing is that only one of these (webappoidc) appears under Enterprise applications blade like following screenshot shows

[image]

So why does Azure behaves this way and how to make my app registrations appear inside Enterprise apps?

Comment: Is there a difference in the way app registrations are created for the apps that show up and don't show up in the enterprise apps?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes, the ones that do not appear created using cli as `az ad app create --display-name "MembersApiApp"`

If I create using azure portal it appears in Enterprise apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an app registration through Azure Portal, the app has `Users.Read` permission however when you create the same using `az ad app create --display-name "MembersApiApp"`, you will notice that the app registration does not have any permissions.

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#service-principal-object), an Enterprise App is automatically created when an application is given permission to access resources in a tenant (upon registration or consent).

[image]

Considering you created app registrations without permissions, they will not show up in Enterprise Apps.

I thought that giving permissions to an app registration created using Azure CLI will automatically add it to Enterprise Apps but that didn't happen. I believe a user has to consent to such applications for them to show under Enterprise apps.

**UPDATE**

Based on my limited research, even if you create an app registration with permissions a Service Principal is not created automatically when using CLI. You would need to explicitly create a Service Principal using [`az ad sp create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is definitely correct. But, can you advice me the most suitable CLI way to create app registration and service principal (enterprise app)? Or may be it is even better to use graph api for role management?

Comment: Once you have created the application, you can create a Service Principal using [`az ad sp create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create). So, essentially a 2 step process.

Comment: I've noticed that even after creating the SP, it doesn't show up in the list of enterprise app registrations - but you can still find it by searching by ObjectID! Any idea why this could be?